# could not start pgAgent due to log on failure

Tags: postgresql, pgagent

I wanted to install pgAgent service on windows. Though it installs alright using the following command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin III\1.14>pgagent.exe INSTALL pgAgent -l2 -u postgres hostaddr=localhost port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres
```

the service does not start giving an error: **Windows could not start pgAgent service on        the local computer. Error 1069: The service did not start due to a logon failure.**

The password is being provided using pgpass.conf file. The same password is being used by pgAdmin to logon to databases.

I have even tried by providing same password (as pgpass.conf) using -p option on the command line itself. It did not work either but error is different. On command line it says **service could not be started. Service reported no error** . However when I see logs in Control Panel/EventViewer following warning is shown:

```
Couldn't create the primary connection (attempt 10): fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

and then an error:

```
Stopping pgAgent: Couldn't establish the primary connection with the database server.
```

If it could help, I downloaded pgAgent separately and placed pgAgent.exe in pgAdmin III/1.14 folder where libpq.dll also resides. I am using PostgreSQL 9.0, pgAdmin 1.14 and pgAgent 3.0.0

Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: Which account is used by the pgAgent service?

Comment: The error message refers to a logon to **Windows** not to Postgres. So a pgpass.conf won't help you there.

Comment: @MilenA.Radev postgres is the account used by pgAgent service which is the same account used by PostgeSQL service as well

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you mean -p option will take a password which is given to PostgeSQL (postgres super user) while installing it first on windows?  and i do not want to provide password using -p option. then how do i do that if not pgpass.conf?

Comment: ok guys, i am able to solve the issue, by reinstalling PostgreSQL and then installing pgAgent with StackBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok guys, i am able to solve the issue, by reinstalling PostgreSQL and then installing pgAgent with StackBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

Go to pgAgent installation folder on windows and execute

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAgent\bin>pgagent REMOVE pgAgent
```

This will remove the existing misconfigured windows service

then reinstall the service in the following way giving the password credentials properly. The first -u gives the postgres user created on windows and the second username in the connection string is the db username. 

 After doing the below start the service and check the Event Viewer if you still see the error.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAgent\bin>pgagent --help
Usage:
pgagent REMOVE <serviceName>
pgagent INSTALL <serviceName> [options] <connect-string>
pgagent DEBUG [options] <connect-string>
options:
-u <user or DOMAIN\user>
-p <password>
-d <displayname>
-t <poll time interval in seconds (default 10)>
-r <retry period after connection abort in seconds (>=10, default 30)>
-l <logging verbosity (ERROR=0, WARNING=1, DEBUG=2, default 0)>

C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAgent\bin>pgagent INSTALL pgAgent -u postgres -p admin
-l 2 hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5433 user=postgres dbname=first password=admin
```