# Start pgAgent Service on Windows 10 with AzureAD login

Tags: postgresql, azure-active-directory, windows-10, pgagent

How can I get the pgAgent Service installed and started on a Windows 10 OS with an AzureAD login?

The pgAgent Service will not start on Windows 10 with a AzureAD login.

My username on this computer is `azuread\my_username` when I run `whoami` from the CLI.

I ran EnterpriseDB’s PostgreSQL Stack Installer as an Administrator to install the pgAgent.  I tried the following values for the "Operating system username":  `my_username`, `azuread\my_username`, `my_username@corpname.com`, and `azuread\my_username@corpname.com`.

Only using `my_username` worked without error.

However, this created a completely different user named `my_username.computername` and put the `pgpass.conf` file in that "users" `%APPDATA%\Roaming\postgresql\` directory.

In my actual user profile, I still cannot start the pgAgent Service.

After installing with `my_username` as the "Operating system username", the pgAgent "Log On As" setting is automatically changed to `.\my_username`.
When trying to start the Service with "Log On As" set to `.\my_username`, I get the following message:
[image]

When installed with or "Log On As" set to any of the other `domain\username` options, I get the following error:
[image]

When running `net start pgAgent-pg16` from an elevated Powershell terminal, I get:

```
The PostgreSQL Scheduling Agent - pgagent-pg16 service is starting...................
The PostgreSQL Scheduling Agent - pgagent-pg16 service could not be started.

The service did not report an error.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3534.
```

---

How can I get the pgAgent Service installed and started on a Windows 10 OS with an AzureAD login?

---

Note: I have seen all of the following SO posts and other instructions and none of them help at all.

- [Unable to install pgagent with application stack builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58798858/unable-to-install-pgagent-with-application-stack-builder)
- [pgAgent install on Windows error: "required systempassword for user:postgres"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77122194/pgagent-install-on-windows-error-required-systempassword-for-userpostgres)
- [How can I install pgAgent for PostgreSQL 9.5 on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66584292/how-can-i-install-pgagent-for-postgresql-9-5-on-windows)
- [How to install pgAgent service on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567168/how-to-install-pgagent-service-on-windows)
- [could not start pgAgent due to log on failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762671/could-not-start-pgagent-due-to-log-on-failure?rq=2)
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/248538/pgagent-service-for-postgresql-does-not-run
- https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/pgagent_install.html#service-installation-on-windows
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html

---

Additionally, when installed, running either `./pgAgent REMOVE pgAgent` or `./pgAgent REMOVE pgAgent-pg16` returns `ERROR: Failed to uninstall source`, and the following does nothing at all.

```
./pgAgent INSTALL pgAgent -u my_Win10_username -p my_Win10_password hostaddr=127.0.0.1 dbaname=postgres user=postgres password=***
```